# How to include number of groups from a panel regression (plm) in stargazer tables

Tags: r, stargazer, plm

Regression result tables are produced via `stargazer` from `plm` objects. Below in the summary part, only Oberservations, R², Adjusted R² and the F Statistic are presented. I would also like to include the number of groups and periods. These appear as "**n**" and "**T**" in the `plm` object.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add those manually.

```
library("plm")
library("stargazer")

data("Produc", package = "plm")

panel_model <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
              data = Produc, 
              index = c("state","year"),
              method="within")

# n (groups) and T (periods) appear in summary
summary(panel_model)
# adding those manually
stargazer(panel_model,type="text", add.lines = list(c("Groups", "48"), c("Periods", "17")))
```

[image]

This and more you find on:

- https://www.jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer/#add-a-custom-row-to-the-reported-statistics

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution works for a clearly arranged set of regression columns. But when you create plenty and/or if the data changes, it'll become hard. Isn't there a solution to include something like Statas ```scalars``` into the stargazer output?